# How to simplify preg_match calls?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
preg_match("/foo1(.*)bar1/", $subject, $matches1);
preg_match("/foo2(.*)bar2/", $subject, $matches2);
preg_match("/foo3(.*)bar3/", $subject, $matches3);
```

I'm wondering how I can combine the three patterns, call `preg_match` only once and put all the matches into one array? As you probably know, `preg_match` doesn't accept an array as first parameter.

Comment: Use alternatives `(foo|bar|baz)`.

Comment: How to use alternatives in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/foo([123])(.*)bar\1/` should do it, using `preg_match_all`, of course. `$matches[2]` will be the array you want.

Comment: Thank you! My question was asked clunky. Actually `fooX` should be only a wildcard for any word even without trailing number. So what would be the solution? Something like this? `preg_match_all("/abc(.*)def|ghi(.*)jkl|mno(.*)pqr/");`

Comment: You can do that, yes, but wrap it so: `/(?|abc(.*)def|...)/` The `?|` there will ensure that all of the matches go into `$matches[1]`.

Comment: "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? at offset 2"

Comment: @a1277399: What is your php version?

Comment: @a1277399: In this case you can try: `/(?<=abc).*(?=def)|(<=ghi).*(?=jkl).../` (in group 0).

Comment: Only the first pattern matches. Do you mean `/(?<=abc).*(?=def)|(?<=ghi).*(?=jkl).../`? That works, but the matches are in reverse order.